# Differntiability of $\cos x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

According to many books, a function is differentiable at $x$ if the left-hand and right-hand derivatives are equal.
It is defined that derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$.
but while finding its LHD and RHD I am not getting the same value $-\sin x$. maybe because I am doing something wrong. 
Kindly take a look and tell me where I am wrong.

[image: Solution page 1]

[image: Solution page 2]

Comment: You did not calculate the one-sided derivatives of $\cos$ at $x$ at all.  Rather, you calculated $-\cos'(x)$ and $\cos'(x)$, respectively, where $\cos'$ denotes the (two-sided) derivative of $\cos$.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: Your "RHD" calculation is just the definition of the (two-sided) derivative $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}.$$  The "LHD" calculation reduces to $-f'(x)$ under the change of variable $h \mapsto -h$.

Comment: The one-sided derivatives are properly defined as $$f'_{-}(x) = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$ and $$f'_{+}(x) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}.$$

Comment: I think you can find the error yourself. You know the answer is $-\sin$, so the error must be in the LHD case. What is wrong with that case? Remember that $h$ is the difference from the left to $x$, not from the right to $x$

Comment: If you want to use both the left- and right-sided derivatives to prove that $\frac{d}{dx}\cos{(x)} = -\sin{(x)}$, then you'd have to use the definitions that @L.F. described. The process is pretty much the exact same for both of them.

Comment: You should not use images. And use MathJax. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.